# Deploying Bitlocker via Unattended OS Installation?

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker, deployment

Is there a way to enable Bitlocker during Windows setup?

Answer (score 1):

There is a post on [minasi.com](http://www.minasi.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=25220) giving an option. I'm not in a position to try it until Monday but it sounds okay.

I'm assuming your attended install currently logs into the "created" user at least once. So, write a batch file that calls [manage-bde](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875513%28WS.10%29.aspx), enables TPM then encrypts then drive. Finally the batch file should delete itself (or the shortcut to it) from the All User's Start Up folder, meaning it won't re-run after that first automated log in.

The batch file should enable the TMP chip (and set the password):

```
manage-bde –tpm –t –o <password>
```

Then encrypt the drive, we'll assume c: and since you aren't at the machine you'll need to get the output of the command written somewhere so you have the Recovery Password. In the example it's going to e:

```
manage-bde –on c: -rp > e:\bitlocker.txt
```

Finally delete the batch file or the shortcut to it and restart the PC.